# Can I print a form or a tabular data in react js?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, web-frontend

Is there a way to send a print command to my printer for printing a tabular data in react js. Sorry if the question sounds silly because I am new to this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggering the browser's native print behavior is quite simple: just call a `window.print()` in your code.

Then your page will be printed as it is, so commonly you should provide a CSS spefic for the *print media*.
You have two way:

- add a separate CSS like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>`
- include a `@media print` in your existing CSS:

`@media print {
   …
}`

What you should put inside your CSS? Whatever you need to fix your styles, commonly a lot of `display: none` rules to hide elements you don't want to print.

Final thoughts:

- print from HTML is not much cross-browser: some browsers print better than other
- printing HTML tables is full of caveats, for example take a look at: [Repeat table headers in print mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274149/repeat-table-headers-in-print-mode)

Answer (score 3):

Call `window.print()` function.

```
print(){
  window.print();
}
```

call this function when you want to print your current screen or component