# Elegant Table Printing CSS - How to re-render column headers for tables spanning multiple pages

Tags: javascript, css, angular

How can I detect if a Table will trigger a new page and conditionally do things that make the printed experience better?

For example, if I have a table that must span a page break (despite intelligent use of the `break-before` / `break-inside` CSS properties), can I detect this and do something like re-render the column headers?  Is there a way that I can detect the size of my output as it is rendered to understand if I'm in a page break zone, and then conditionally reform my html to accomodate?

I'm currently programming in Angular - but any JS/HTML/CSS based solution I'll be able to adapt.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274149/repeat-table-headers-in-print-mode

Comment: Yeah - apparently my google skills failed me.  That gets me 95% where I need to be. Is there a way to detect if I'm at a page break so that I can render borders at the bottom of each page?

Comment: You could add a tfoot element and style that perhaps?