# HTML Table header repeating

Tags: html

I am not sure why my table header is repeating on every page after printing HTML Code. I just want it on first page so how can I do it?

[image]

I wanted it to display only when the table starts

Comment: Can't you just remove it from the other pages?

Comment: @SteveTomlin The question is regarding *printed* pages, where the table header is automatically included by the browser on all pages spanned by the table itself. I thought it might be possible to use [`@page` and `:first`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first) to target the styles only on the first page, but `:first` cannot be used to set display, visibility, etc.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. I was confusing 'pages' with browser pages. I don't think css has any concept of printed pages. A possible option for you is to create 2 tables, (one hidden in the browser with the table head, and the other without)

Comment: @SteveTomlin CSS has some nice controls over printed pages (see `@media print` and `@page` for starters), but not nearly as robust as this issue would require.

Answer (score 0):

What you're observing is the intentional behavior of modern browsers. In fact, for quite some time users here on Stack Overflow would ask [*how to achieve* this behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274149/repeat-table-headers-in-print-mode), prior to it seeing broad support in browsers.

My suggestion would be to *leave this behavior as-is*, since it provides important context across page-breaks. After all, if you provide 6 pages of tabular data, and page 3 is reviewed on its own, how will the handler know what data is represented by the values unless there is a header to explain the information?

If you feel strongly that the repeated header is not needed, then there may be another approach you can take. You could show the `thead` for web-viewers, and replace it with a single `tr` (containing the same information) for printed viewers. For example:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="faux-header">
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1, Cell 1</td>
            <td>Row 1, Cell 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You wouldn't want the faux-header visible by default, and you wouldn't want the `thead` to be visible in a printed context:

```css
@media screen {
    .faux-header {
        display: none;
    }

}

@media print {
    table:has(.faux-header) thead {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use td instead of th tag for quick fix like `<td>Preventive Care</td>`

Comment: I would discourage this approach for several reasons. First, it doesn't work. Browsers will still repeat the `THEAD` element across pages. Secondly, it conflates `TD` and `TH` elements, which are distinctly different, and should not be confused. Third, this approach wouldn't explicitly communicate the author's intention to hide `THEAD` elements after the first page.